# Вывод символа unicode в Java в консоли

Tags: java, консоль, windows-7, unicode

только начала изучать Java. у меня задание вывести в консоли "Hello World! (и здесь юникод->)**пингвин и сердце"** 
если с выводом текста хэллоу ворлд все ясно, то вывести в консоль юникод никак не получается.

Comment: преобразуйте каждый символ в char в виде массива. Теперь пройдитесь по нему, используя "char".codePointAt(0)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать `\u` для вывода Юникод-символов, например
`System.out.println("\u0068\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f");` выведет `hello`;
`System.out.println("Hello World! \u27a1 пингвин и сердце");` выведет `Hello World! ➡ пингвин и сердце`;

Конвертировать строку в юникод можно здесь: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter.

Надеюсь помог.

Answer (score 1):

Сердечко так можно вывести

```
System.out.println("\u2764 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Строки и отдельные символы (`char`) в Java всегда закодированы в юникоде (в UTF-16). Исходный код Java, по умолчанию, так же должен быть записан в UTF-16 (что позволяет использовать нелатинские буквы в именах переменных, классов и прочего). По этому всё что вам необходимо - настроить поддержку юникода в вашей консоле.

Иногда кодировка исходного кода может отличаться от UTF-16 (например если она не определена в pom.xml, Maven будет использовать системную 8-и битную кодировку). Для таких случаев или для перестраховки можно использовать запись символов в формате `\uxxxx` где `xxxx` - это шестнадцатеричное представление UTF-16 символа.